# How to pass nested json object through soapui in request api

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I am new to REST and i am making test cases for server client application. where server is made in php using symphony framework and clients are available both in android and ios. Server implements Rest instead of Soap. Now i have to make a test case in soapui to add a group in which nested JSON parameter is going but i am failed to send parameter as nested. I can show you the request from the log on server side.

[2014-09-24 11:14:36] las_api.INFO:

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "http:\/\/192.168.1.134\/las_web\/web\/app_dev.php\/api\/users\/2\/groups.json",
    "attributes": {
      "_controller": "Las\\ApiBundle\\Controller\\User\\GroupController::cpostAction",
      "_format": "json",
      "userId": "2",
      "_route": "api_post_user_groups",
      "_route_params": {
        "_format": "json",
        "userId": "2"
      }
    },
    "post": {
      "group": {
        "name": "Seniors"
      },
      "token": "{81A9B0D9-CA0E-E70F-ADFF-116EE7A1A980}"
    },
    "get": [

    ]
  },
  "ip": "192.168.1.134"
}
```

Below is the parameter request parameter. where in group there are two parameters first is  name of the group and second is the token generated by server       on login time.

```
{
  "group": {
    "name": "Seniors"
  },
  "token": "{81A9B0D9-CA0E-E70F-ADFF-116EE7A1A980}"
}
```

I have successfully made test case for login. I can show you the request from server log while logging.

[2014-09-24 10:11:37] las_api.INFO:

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "http:\/\/192.168.1.134\/las_web\/web\/app_dev.php\/api\/tokens",
    "attributes": {
      "_controller": "Las\\ApiBundle\\Controller\\TokenController::cpostAction",
      "_format": "json",
      "_route": "api_post_tokens",
      "_route_params": {
        "_format": "json"
      }
    },
    "post": {
      "password": "abc123",
      "username": "abc@gmail.com"
    },
    "get": [

    ]
  },
  "ip": "192.168.1.134"
}
```

Comment: You can format text as code by indenting it four spaces. It makes it much easier to read. Click the edit link by your post to make the changes. You should also post the code you are using to create the JSON--as it is, there is no indication of what language you are using. See [how to ask a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I cleaned up your code somewhat. I still do not understand what you mean by "nested JSON"; perhaps you are confused on the terminology? But most important: I do not understand what the problem is!